# Text Wrap using return and print

Tags: python

You are given a string `S` and width `w`.
Your task is to wrap the string `S` into a paragraph of width `w`.
Input Format
The first line contains a string, `S`.
The second line contains the width, `w`.

**Sample Input**

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLIMNOQRSTUVWXYZ
4
```

**Sample Output**

```
ABCD
EFGH
IJKL
IMNO
QRST
UVWX
YZ
```

I tried the code, but didn't get the required result. As 2 extra lines are coming in the output.
*Also Note: Last 4 lines in the code is immutable(not to be changed)*

```
import textwrap

def wrap(string, max_width):
    y=max_width
    z=0

    for i in range(0,len(string),y):
        print(string[0+z:y+z])
        z+=max_width


if __name__ == '__main__':
    string, max_width = input(), int(input())
    result = wrap(string, max_width)
    print(result)
```

Comment: What was your actual result? Using a library seems like overkill; have you considered just parsing the string `S`?

Comment: The result was:ABCD
EFGH
IJKL
IMNO
QRST
UVWX
YZ
None

Comment: your idea is close but your function isnt returning anything as the result. you dont want to print the output in your function you want to build a string to return and then let the line `print(result)` deal with the output

Answer (score 1):

```
a="ABCDEFGHIJKLIMNOQRSTUVWXYZ"
k=0
h=4
for i in range(7):
    print(a[k:h])
    k=h
    h=h+4
    
# only consumes 95bytes.
```

Comment: import textwrap
string = "ABCDEFGHIJKLIMNOQRSTUVWXYZ"
print(textwrap.fill(string,4)) #its also similar

Answer (score 1):

Try this its a bit smaller and less sophisticated

```
import textwrap

def wrap(string, max_width):
    text = textwrap.fill(string,max_width)
    return text

if __name__ == '__main__':
    string, max_width = input(), int(input())
    result = wrap(string, max_width)
    print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

your idea was right, but you didnt build up a string in your function to return to the calling code for the main code to print it.

```
def wrap(string, max_width):
    y=max_width
    z=0
    return_string = ""   #Create an empty string that we will build as we go
    for i in range(0,len(string),y):
        return_string += string[0+z:y+z] + "\n"  #append the chars to the string with a new line
        z+=max_width
    return return_string

if __name__ == '__main__':
    string, max_width = input(), int(input())
    result = wrap(string, max_width)
    print(result)
```

This could also be written as a list comprehension and joined with new lines

```
def wrap(string, max_width):
    return "\n".join([string[i:i+max_width] for i in range(0, len(string) - 1, max_width)])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(one extra line is coming)
import textwrap

def wrap(string, max_width):
    i=0
    j=max_width
    n=(len(string)//max_width)+(len(string)%max_width)

    for l in range(0,n-1):
        print(string[i:j:])
        i=i+max_width
        j=j+max_width
    
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    string, max_width = input(), int(input())
    result = wrap(string, max_width)
    print(result)
```